# Precision problems when rendering whole planets

Tags: opengl, glsl, precision

I'm trying to implement a camera, which is able to go very close to a planet/moon surface, without flickering surface.

**The problem:**
Right now the position of a planet / moon is saved at the center of the planet / moon. When looking at the earth, its radius is ~6371km. So when creating a sphere with such a radius the problem starts when the camera is very close to the surface. The surface (ground) bumps up and down like randomly (~1 meter) which I am trying to prevent.
This behavior is simple to understand: The vertex position in VBO is like 6371km away from the origin. And the camera (when it is close to the surface) is also like 6371km away from the planets center. So the viewmatrix is working with such high numbers, so that the result (position) flickers because of the floating precision. Right now I am using km as base unit. To use meter or other units as baseunit will not solve the problem, because it only shifts the comma. So the problem is that I need more, than the I think it was 8 digits of precision a float has, to avoid the flickering. So using doubles would solve the problem, but as far as I found, double vectors are available in GLSL, but double matrices not.
Are there other algorithms which I can use?

later I want to tessellate the mesh in camera region and put a heightmap on top of it to visualize mountains. I also would like to add Simplex-noise on top of it to have a realistic surface.

**The idea I have right now:** To describe my idea in a simpler way I'll use a 2D representation of the problem.
In the image below you can see several parts of a circle. These meshes will be used depending on the camera distance to the surface like LOD. So when being far away from the planet, the circle (sphere) should be rendered. when coming closer, smaller parts of the planet will be visible. The black dot represents the real center of the planet. The red dot represents the origin of the mesh (VBO) which will be calculated on CPU (double) before rendering the scenario. This sub mesh need to be rotated so that the camera will always be in a line with the black and red dot.
[image]

As you can see, the red dot is moving towards the camera, so the precision problem will be solved. What is problematic here is, that the earth for example is not a sphere but a ellipsoid. So the sub-parts somehow need to be scaled non uniformly. But I think that other heads (better ones) already thought about a perfect solution for that problem.

Comment: Use a smaller scaling to correspond to 6371km.

Comment: like I wrote it does not work. so for a radius of 6371km I would need a 0.000001 km precision. for a 6.371 mega meter I would need a 0.000000001 mega meter precision. So it is the same problem

Comment: so the problem is that the value needs more digits than a float can store with 1bit +- 8bit exponent and 23bit mantissa so the result with different units would only change the exponent value and therefore only changes the comma position

Comment: Partition your space and work at different precisions/lods for different parts. When you start nearing a planet switch to a higher lod and rescale things appropriately. At certain scales it's fine to have the planets as just sphere and using one scale, when you get closer to a planet you can keep the faraway ones at lower lod and increase the lod only for the ones you are closer to. Don't use too large numbers when scaling your world,  try smaller numbers and just pretend that they correspond to something larger.

Comment: Did you consider using plain old integers? They have the full 2^32 precision.

Comment: @pmw1234 to be honest, I didn't had that in mind. But how would it work? saying, that 1 millimeter is one unit? And just use integers? How would the viewmatrix look like?

Comment: millimeter? meters or decimeters would be better, the smallest real time modeling I have seen is 10 inches at the planet scale. To do this you create an integer global world space that translates positions from it, into a local world space that is in floating point. From there on everything works like normal. All the world objects/terrain is stored in global world space and goes through the same translation. The extra computations can be done in the vertex shader to help minimize the performance impact. (Each frame the position of the camera becomes the local world space origin)

Comment: What do you mean by "global world space that translates positions from it"? Do you have a link where someone is doing this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It means camera is static and all objects move to fit this. Its not such a big problem of the precision of a faraway object diminishes.